# Archivo corrupto con PHPWord

Tags: codeigniter, phpword

Estoy trabajando con la librería PhpWord y el archivo templateProcess.php para generar documentos basados en templates, actualmente funciona de forma correcta si sólo agrego texto.

Sin embargo al querer agregar imágenes el archivo se genera como corrupto.

¿A alguien le ha sucedido?

Este fragmento uso para crear buscar y reemplazar las imágenes dentro de la plantilla.

```
    $templateWord->cloneRow("equipo_nombre", $count_items);

    for ($i=1; $i <= $cantidad_planes; $i++) { 
        $templateWord->setValue('equipo_nombre#'.$i, $data[0]->contenido[$i-1]['caracteristicas']['marca']['nombre_marca'] ." ". $data[0]->contenido[$i-1]['caracteristicas']['modelo']['nombre_modelo']);
        $source = 'assets/media/productos/0cd36903c57479d99943d915710c20e6.jpg';

        $templateWord->setImageValue('equipo_foto#'.$i, 'equipo_foto.png', $source);
    }

 $filename = 'cotizacion_'.date('YmdHms').'.docx';
 $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/admin/assets/".$filename; 
 $templateWord->saveAs($target_file);
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: hola, si en `$source = 'assets/media/productos/0cd36903c57479d99943d915710c20e6.jpg';
` le agregas un **./** antes quedando de esta forma `$source = './assets/media/productos/0cd36903c57479d99943d915710c20e6.jpg';
`

Comment: Aún de esa forma el Word sigue generándose corrupto. 

La ruta no creo que sea el problema ya que cuando agrego imagen "si se inserta al archivo"  pero al descargarse se genera corrupto. 

Cuando solo es texto el archivo abre correctamente.

Comment: Después de varias pruebas pude encontrar una solución y fue añadiendo una imagen previamente al template en Word.

Al parecer, se genera un error al abrir el docx y crear la carpeta media por primera vez.